# Javascript creating an object to store all data and display information

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a ‘customer’ object that will store all of this data and then display the information as a ‘Customer Order’ similar with listing all the new information.
I can't figure out what's the problem. (Pretty sure the whole code itself is messed up)
When I run it, it also shows 'ReferenceError: clicked is not defined' message.
I don't understand the concept of storing data and displaying new information as a 'Customer Order'.

This is my javascript.

```js
/*index.js*/

var objectarray = [];
function addToArray() {

  var customerobject = {
    name: "",
    address: "",
    postalcode: "",
    phone: "",
    email: ""
  }
  customerobject.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  customerobject.address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  customerobject.postalcode = document.getElementById("postalcode").value;
  customerobject.phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  customerobject.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  objectarray.push(customerobject);
  console.log(objectarray);

}
document.getElementById("buttonandchecks").addEventListener("click", clicked);


function clicked() {
  addToArray();
}
<input id="name" value="Jenna" />
<input id="address" value="840 9STREET" />
<input id="postalcode" value="T2P 2T4" />
<input id="phone" value="111-111-1111" />
<input id="email" value="Renee@gmail.com" />
<button id="clickMe">click me</button>



function buttonandchecks()

{

 //javascripts to get an output based on customer information

   

}

> ------------------------Below is my html------------------------
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="this.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="this.js">
</script>


</head>



<body>
<br>
<form name="information">
<table>
<tr><td>;   First and Last Name :;</td><td><input type="name" id="nameid" size="25" maxlength="25" autofocus="yes" pattern="[a-zA-Z -]+$"></td></tr>
<tr><td>;   Address :;</td><td><input type="address" id="addressid" size="25" maxlength="25" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]| |/|,|.|\|@|#|$|%|&)+"></td></tr>
<tr><td>;   Phone Number :;</td><td><input type="tel" size="25" id="phoneid" placeholder="XXX XXX XXXX" pattern="\d{3} \d{3} \d{4}"></td></tr>
</form>

<form name=order>
//javascript to get an customer information
<br>

<br>

<center><input type=button value="Price your Order" id="clickMe" onClick="clicked();"></center>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off, you cannot have HTML inside Javascript the way you do.

Comment: Also, where is the `#buttonandchecks` element?

Comment: `onClick="clicked();` why semicolon?

Comment: @Raymond What do you mean by that?

Comment: @showdev How can I add buttonandchecks element?

Comment: You'd write it in HTML. Something like `<button id="buttonandchecks">Click Me</button>`. You reference it in your JavaScript but there's no such element in your document. Maybe you meant the `#clickMe` element? Just one of many issues.

Comment: Raymond means that you've got HTML like `<input id="name" value="Jenna" />` mixed in with your JavaScript code. That will cause errors and break stuff. But maybe your real code is not like that and it's just a problem with formatting it here on SO. I was just trying to reproduce your error but I couldn't get that far because the code seems malformed.

Comment: I fixed your code below as an answer. You should be posting the form data to a service, or posting the array to a service when you're done filling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed your code, but there is a lot more to this question. This isn't really a proper way to store the data. You should be posting the information from the form to a service.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input id="name" value="Jenna" />
    <input id="address" value="840 9STREET" />
    <input id="postalcode" value="T2P 2T4" />
    <input id="phone" value="111-111-1111" />
    <input id="email" value="Renee@gmail.com" />
    <button id="clickMe">click me</button>
  </body>  
  <script>
    var objectarray = [];
    var button = document.getElementById("clickMe");

    function addToArray() {
      var customerobject = {};
      customerobject.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      customerobject.address = document.getElementById("address").value;
      customerobject.postalcode = document.getElementById("postalcode").value;
      customerobject.phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
      customerobject.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      objectarray.push(customerobject);
      console.log(objectarray);
    }
    button.addEventListener("click", addToArray);
  </script>
</html>
```